# Blocking non-CRUD REST verbs

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, mapping

We have a requirement in our current (Spring) web application to only allow CRUD-based REST calls (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).  This is for security scans to prevent cross-site scripting attacks, etc. so we have to make these changes.  We want a response like a 405 to be returned if the call is not one of these methods.

We do have all of our Controller request methods mapped only to the specific methods they are required to respond to, but requests other than those return mixed results.  For example, if I have a @RequestMapping defined as a GET, but I try to make a call to that service with an OPTIONS method, I get a 200 response, but when I call the same method using TRACE, I get a 405.

I am fairly new at Spring, so I first attempted to write a custom interceptor implementation from HandlerInterceptorAdapter, but by that time, the two examples above have already been intercepted so this solution isn't what we're looking for.

What options do I have to accomplish this, with either Spring, Java, Tomcat, or Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Requests can be mapped to `OPTIONS`, `TRACE` or `HEAD` too. Implement methods for these HTTP requests and return a response of your choice, e.g. 405. Check the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method%28%29).